# How to project a Windows 10 to my LG TV

Tags: windows, tv, xbox360, miracast

I am using Thinkpad E530 and I can see the PC can discover the LG TV from my Device Manager.
[image]

However, when I was trying to Connect to this TV by clicking the Connect
[image]

It shows my PC doesn't support Miracast...
[image]

My questions:

1. Now, I am confused, because if it doesn't support Miracast, why I can see the LG TV from my Device Manager?
2. If I could not make it work by configuring my PC, then what hardware I need to buy to have the Miracast functionality?
3. By the way, I have an Xbox 360, so is it possible to connect to my LG TV somehow via the Xbox?

Thanks

Comment: Have you every connected your TV to your computer using a cable? Have you used some other utility to connect to the TV? Have you installed a utility from LG on your computer for the purpose of connecting your TV?

Comment: Also, please limit each post to a single specific question so that a single specific answer can be posted.

Comment: No, I just moved into this new apartment, and this is my friend's TV. Never installed anything related to this TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I can use the Film & TV app on Windows 10 to cast movies to my TV directly without XBOX 360.

Not sure how to make the tv my 3rd screen via Wireless casting.

Comment: Making your TV a 3rd screen requires your TV to support WiDi or Miracast (these are essentially the same thing, but the standard is either not well defined or it is not well controlled and there are implementations that are not compatible with each other).

Comment: thanks @music2myear I was gonna to ask since I can do Movie casting via an app, why I cannot use the Miracast. then saw your comment.